# Will apple let me use a customized keyboard?

Tags: iphone, sdk

I want to customize my keyboad to look different. ie, another background color.

Will apple let me do that?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do that if you want to sell your app in the App Store and conform to Apple's UI Guidelines.

Comment: And if I change it entirly to look like a dialog box or another design?